# Python Buildozer Command failed

Tags: android, python, ubuntu

I want to create an Android-App, but when I write "buildozer android debug deploy" in the terminal of ubuntu 14.10 - which is on an usb device-, but I get an error:

**SWT folder '/home/ubuntu/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-21/tools/lib/x86' does not exist.
Please export ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing swt.jar for your platform.
Command failed: /home/ubuntu/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-21/tools/android list sdk -u -e**

Before I get the error buildozer checks whether some things (Android SDK&NDK is installed...). I don't know what to do. Maybe it's because I use other requirements (except for kivy) like  os, threading, pytube?
I hope You can help me thanks ;).